# Interact with an invisible element and access second matching element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-select

I want to select a value from a drop-down option. The html is as follows:
(the website is http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByAirport.do)

```
<select id="airportQueryTime" name="airportQueryTime" onchange="selectTime(this); return true;" value="6">
 <option onchange="selectTime(this); return true;" selected="selected" value="6">
  6:00AM - 7:00AM
 </option>
 <option onchange="selectTime(this); return true;" value="7">
  7:00AM - 8:00AM
 </option>
 <option onchange="selectTime(this); return true;" value="8">
  8:00AM - 9:00AM
 </option>
 <option onchange="selectTime(this); return true;" value="9">
</select>



from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = 'http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByAirport.do;jsessionid=7B477D6D5CFB639F96C5D855CEB941D0.web4:8009?airport=LAX&airportQueryDate=2014-09-06&airportQueryTime=-1&airlineToFilter=&airportQueryType=0&x=0&y=0'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(6)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='airportQueryTime']/option[@value='0']")
element.click()
```

My question is:

1. Because there are three tag if I find element by ID = 'airportQueryTime', and the element I need is the second one. HOW TO ACCESS THE SECOND MATCHING ELEMENT?
2. I am trying to select the option value = 0 using the following code, but selenium raise an error.

   selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selenium` has a special [`Select`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) class for interacting with `select` and `option` tags:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


url = 'http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByAirport.do;jsessionid=7B477D6D5CFB639F96C5D855CEB941D0.web4:8009?airport=LAX&airportQueryDate=2014-09-06&airportQueryTime=-1&airlineToFilter=&airportQueryType=0&x=0&y=0'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='uiComponent674']//select[@id='airportQueryTime']"))

# print all the options
print [element.text for element in select.options]

# select option by text
select.select_by_visible_text('6:00AM - 7:00AM')
```

Note that, since there are multiple elements with `airportQueryTime` id on the page, we have to  search for it in the scope of `div` with `uiComponent674` class (block for choosing time intervals).

Comment: You are so great! I don't know that there's a class "SELECT" in selenium. By the way, do you know where I can find some advanced documentation for selenium? The http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/ is not good enough XD

Comment: @MacSanhe thanks, well, I usually use selenium-python.readthedocs.org, it is really not that bad. Do you remember what were you trying to find there and haven't found?

Comment: Like I didn't see any chapter explain how to use:from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

Comment: @MacSanhe I was the maintainer of that docs, but I don't work on Selenium these days. If somebody sends any pull request, I can review and add it.